# Dynamically load coordinates to google map from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

as I go through with my studies on web dev and ajax; i came across with this template that has a map(google map) on it. the script for loading the map is placed on an external .js file here is the code.

```
    function LoadMapProperty() {
    var locations = new Array(
        [14.4718329, 121.0086019], [14.530026, 120.996063], [14.4737421, 121.0032217], [14.5075023, 120.993699],
        [14.5075023, 120.993699], [14.471466, 121.0277539], [14.4779355, 120.99883], [14.4731542, 121.0037827],
        [14.4966062, 120.9884816], [14.4926289, 120.98628], [14.4779355, 120.99883], [14.4663681, 121.0085009],
        [14.4965154, 120.9895496], [14.527833, 120.996831], [14.4849982, 120.9869173], [14.5016121, 120.9960593],
        [14.4745177, 120.9987967], [14.4745177, 120.9987967], [14.5292715, 120.9960647], [14.4798793, 120.9983465],
        [14.530001, 120.995553], [14.4745177, 120.9987967], [14.4745177, 120.9987967], [14.5292715, 120.9960647],
        [14.4901257, 120.9883528], [14.4799374, 120.9978811], [14.4678564, 120.9801271], [14.4745177, 120.9987967],
        [14.503642, 120.994828], [14.5002999, 120.9973589], [14.5292715, 120.9960647], [14.51565, 120.9960106]
    );
    var markers = new Array();
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.4718329, 121.0086019),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('property-map'), mapOptions);

    $.each(locations, function(index, location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            map: map,
            icon: 'http://html.realia.byaviators.com/assets/img/marker-transparent.png'
        });

        var myOptions = {
            content: '<div class="infobox"><div class="image"><img src="http://html.realia.byaviators.com/assets/img/tmp/property-tiny-1.png" alt=""></div><div class="title"><a href="detail.html">1041 Fife Ave</a></div><div class="area"><span class="key">Area:</span><span class="value">200m<sup>2</sup></span></div><div class="price">€450 000.00</div><div class="link"><a href="detail.html">View more</a></div></div>',
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 0,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-146, -190),
            zIndex: null,
            closeBoxURL: "",
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            isHidden: false,
            pane: "floatPane",
            enableEventPropagation: false
        };
        marker.infobox = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        marker.infobox.isOpen = false;

        var myOptions = {
            draggable: true,
            content: '<div class="marker"><div class="marker-inner"></div></div>',
            disableAutoPan: true,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-21, -58),
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            closeBoxURL: "",
            isHidden: false,
            // pane: "mapPane",
            enableEventPropagation: true
        };
        marker.marker = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        marker.marker.open(map, marker);
        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            var curMarker = this;

            $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
                // if marker is not the clicked marker, close the marker
                if (marker !== curMarker) {
                    marker.infobox.close();
                    marker.infobox.isOpen = false;
                }
            });


            if(curMarker.infobox.isOpen === false) {
                curMarker.infobox.open(map, this);
                curMarker.infobox.isOpen = true;
                map.panTo(curMarker.getPosition());
            } else {
                curMarker.infobox.close();
                curMarker.infobox.isOpen = false;
            }

        });
    });
}

function LoadMap() {
    var locations = new Array(
        [14.4718329, 121.0086019], [14.530026, 120.996063], [14.4737421, 121.0032217], [14.5075023, 120.993699],
        [14.5075023, 120.993699], [14.471466, 121.0277539], [14.4779355, 120.99883], [14.4731542, 121.0037827],
        [14.4966062, 120.9884816], [14.4926289, 120.98628], [14.4779355, 120.99883], [14.4663681, 121.0085009],
        [14.4965154, 120.9895496], [14.527833, 120.996831], [14.4849982, 120.9869173], [14.5016121, 120.9960593],
        [14.4745177, 120.9987967], [14.4745177, 120.9987967], [14.5292715, 120.9960647], [14.4798793, 120.9983465],
        [14.530001, 120.995553], [14.4745177, 120.9987967], [14.4745177, 120.9987967], [14.5292715, 120.9960647],
        [14.4901257, 120.9883528], [14.4799374, 120.9978811], [14.4678564, 120.9801271], [14.4745177, 120.9987967],
        [14.503642, 120.994828], [14.5002999, 120.9973589], [14.5292715, 120.9960647], [14.51565, 120.9960106]
    );
    var markers = new Array();
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.4718329, 121.0086019),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $.each(locations, function(index, location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            map: map,
            icon: 'http://html.realia.byaviators.com/assets/img/marker-transparent.png'
        });

        var myOptions = {
            content: '<div class="infobox"><div class="image"><img src="http://html.realia.byaviators.com/assets/img/tmp/property-tiny-1.png" alt=""></div><div class="title"><a href="detail.html">1041 Fife Ave</a></div><div class="area"><span class="key">Area:</span><span class="value">200m<sup>2</sup></span></div><div class="price">€450 000.00</div><div class="link"><a href="detail.html">View more</a></div></div>',
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 0,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-146, -190),
            zIndex: null,
            closeBoxURL: "",
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            isHidden: false,
            pane: "floatPane",
            enableEventPropagation: false
        };
        marker.infobox = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        marker.infobox.isOpen = false;

        var myOptions = {
            draggable: true,
            content: '<div class="marker"><div class="marker-inner"></div></div>',
            disableAutoPan: true,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-21, -58),
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            closeBoxURL: "",
            isHidden: false,
            // pane: "mapPane",
            enableEventPropagation: true
        };
        marker.marker = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        marker.marker.open(map, marker);
        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            var curMarker = this;

            $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
                // if marker is not the clicked marker, close the marker
                if (marker !== curMarker) {
                    marker.infobox.close();
                    marker.infobox.isOpen = false;
                }
            });


            if(curMarker.infobox.isOpen === false) {
                curMarker.infobox.open(map, this);
                curMarker.infobox.isOpen = true;
                map.panTo(curMarker.getPosition());
            } else {
                curMarker.infobox.close();
                curMarker.infobox.isOpen = false;
            }

        });
    });
}

function InitMap() {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', LoadMap);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', LoadMapProperty);
}
```

I am new with this ajax thing and as i said just trying to learn things. as with the code you'll notice that the coordinates are bundled in an array. so my question is, Is there a way where in I can fetch some coordinates from my database and put them in this .js script? any links on  other website, suggestions or hint is much appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that should help you get started.

```
function addMarkers(map, locations) {
    $.each(locations, function(index, location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            map: map,
            icon: 'http://html.realia.byaviators.com/assets/img/marker-transparent.png'
        });

        var myOptions = {
            content: '<div class="infobox"><div class="image"><img src="http://html.realia.byaviators.com/assets/img/tmp/property-tiny-1.png" alt=""></div><div class="title"><a href="detail.html">1041 Fife Ave</a></div><div class="area"><span class="key">Area:</span><span class="value">200m<sup>2</sup></span></div><div class="price">€450 000.00</div><div class="link"><a href="detail.html">View more</a></div></div>',
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 0,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-146, -190),
            zIndex: null,
            closeBoxURL: "",
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            isHidden: false,
            pane: "floatPane",
            enableEventPropagation: false
        };
        marker.infobox = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        marker.infobox.isOpen = false;

        var myOptions = {
            draggable: true,
            content: '<div class="marker"><div class="marker-inner"></div></div>',
            disableAutoPan: true,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-21, -58),
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            closeBoxURL: "",
            isHidden: false,
            // pane: "mapPane",
            enableEventPropagation: true
        };
        marker.marker = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        marker.marker.open(map, marker);
        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
            var curMarker = this;

            $.each(markers, function(index, marker) {
                // if marker is not the clicked marker, close the marker
                if (marker !== curMarker) {
                    marker.infobox.close();
                    marker.infobox.isOpen = false;
                }
            });


            if (curMarker.infobox.isOpen === false) {
                curMarker.infobox.open(map, this);
                curMarker.infobox.isOpen = true;
                map.panTo(curMarker.getPosition());
            } else {
                curMarker.infobox.close();
                curMarker.infobox.isOpen = false;
            }

        });
    });
}
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqXHR object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "getlocations.php" ).done(function() {
    addMarkers(map, locations)
});
```

Basically, the code fetches data from the script on getlocations.php and calls addMarkers using the data (it must be returned in JSON form) in "locations". You can add parameters to the AJAX to make it more flexible, like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
type: "GET",
url: "getlocations.php",
data: { city: "Boston", page: 1 } // or whatever parameters you need to send in the URL
}).done(function() {
    addMarkers(map, locations)
});
```